# Some attributed strings crash when drawn

Tags: ios, swift, draw, nsattributedstring

I am trying to draw attributed strings onto a UIView using Xcode 6.0.1 with a target of iPad2 iOS 7.1

I find that some strings draw ok but others crash the app.

After much experimentation I have isolated the problem in the following code:

```
import UIKit

class myview: UIView
{

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let tick = "✓"
        let x = "t"
        let xtick="✓t"

        // try next line with c=tick, then c=x and then c=xtick

        let c=tick
        var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold",   size:54.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]

        c.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(80,220), withAttributes:attrs)
    }
}
```

With `c = tick` or `c = xtick` all is OK but if you `let c = x` the app crashes.

If you comment out the `drawAtPoint` line there is no crash so this is the trigger.

The first crash message is:

> -[__NSCFType set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aee4f00

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Are you sure you have to call `CGColor` on `UIColor.greenColor()`?

Comment: @Levi: I think you have the right answer.

Comment: That seems to work! - but still seems strange that some strings were ok and other not. Will test in the main app --- thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You are using CGColor with UIColor please remove .CGColor from attributed sting it will working fine. Its Working fine in iOS 9 but in lower version its not supporting thats why this issue genrating.

```
var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold",   size:54.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.greenColor()];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a `UIColor` instead of a `CGColorRef`, so remove the `CGColor` and leave only this:

```
var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold",   size:54.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.greenColor()]
```